# Create new SharePoint user with REST api

Tags: rest

Is it possible to Create a new user in SharePoint? I tried the below but it doesn't work. We use `ThinkTecture` as the identity provider and not the default SharePoint authentication.

`POST https://<siteurl>/_api/Web/Siteusers HTTP/1.1`

`POST BODY : {"__metadata":{"type":"SP.User"},"LoginName":"i:05.t|identity server|user@domain.com"}`

I get a 404 - The user does not exist or is not unique.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try [EnsureUser   method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj245233.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to check whether the specified login name belongs to a valid user in the site. If the user doesn't exist, adds the user to the site.

**Example**

```
function ensureUser(accountName)
{
    var endpointUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/ensureUser('" + encodeURIComponent(accountName) + "')";
    return $.ajax({       
       url: endpointUrl,   
       type: "POST",  
       contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
       headers: { 
          "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
          "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
       }
    });
}


var accountName = 'i:0#.f|membership|jdoe@contoso.onmicrosoft.com';
ensureUser(accountName)
.done(function(data)
{
   console.log('Done.');   
})
.fail(function(error){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
});
```

Comment: Thanks Vadim :) I had already implemented the same. Thanks for your reponse :)

Comment: - For AD users: just use the AD username, not the domain neither anything else ( no need to encoudeURIcomponent ).
- Ensure you add "charset=utf-8" to your headers ( content & accept )

Answer (score 0):

It's actually only a comment on the answer of @VadimGremyachev, not intended as an answer, but it was too long for a comment.

Although I've not tested the suggestion of @Alberto (e.g. using the username without doamin for AD users), the life is not always so simple. For example, we have multiple domains, having several users with the very same user name in more than one of the domains (like domain1\jdoe, domain2\jdoe). If you should include the domain name as well, you will face issues you don't have with the `ThinkTecture` identity provider. In this case, the answer of @VadimGremyachev won't work.
As the answer [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/160686/6919) suggest, you should URL encode only the membership provider part (like 'i:0#.w|') but not the user name (like 'domain\user'). Due to the backslash in the path, you get then the following error:

```
A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client at System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateInputIfRequiredByConfig()
```

Alternative solutions:

```
/_api/Web/EnsureUser(@v)?@v='i%3A0%23.w%7Cdomain\user'
```

or send the login name in the payload / request body without (!) encoding anything as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33261452/704022):

```
function ensureUser(webUrl,loginName)
{
   var payload = { 'logonName': loginName }; 
   return $.ajax({
      url: webUrl + "/_api/web/ensureuser",
      type: "POST",
      contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
      data: JSON.stringify(payload),
      headers: {
         "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
         "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
      }
   });  
}


var loginName = 'i:0#.f|membership|jdoe@contoso.onmicrosoft.com'
ensureUser(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl,loginName)
.done(function(data)
{
    console.log('User has been added');
})
.fail(function(error){
    console.log('An error occured while adding user');
});
```

Remark: the same solutions should work for other identity providers (like `ThinkTecture`) as well, however, in cases where there is no (back)slash in the login name, the solution suggested by @VadimGremyachev provides a more simple approach.