# Inserting a user into a person field in sharepoint using the rest api

Tags: 2013

Im trying to update a list item in a remote sharepoint site using the rest api from a workflow. Im having issues understanding how to populate a person field. Ive lookied online and read that you should use the id of the user and not the login, however what if i do not know the users id? Where can i get this from?

Ive been reading the following link but it doesnt explain where the id comes from

[how to add user to sharepoint list item user field using REST api in sp2013?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16500077/how-to-add-user-to-sharepoint-list-item-user-field-using-rest-api-in-sp2013)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Id comes from the User Information List in the Site Collection.
You can ask the users id from this list also via rest.

Example here: (User properties)
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn531432.aspx

You need to call `ensureUser`, which adds it to the Site Collection User list if the user is not already existing.

[Create new SharePoint user with REST api](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/142984/create-new-sharepoint-user-with-rest-api)

Comment: Thats exactly what ive started doing but what happens if the user isnt in the user information list.

Comment: hm then you need to add the user first

Comment: how about this:; http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/142984/create-new-sharepoint-user-with-rest-api  explains how to add user via rest.

Comment: thanks alot i forgot about ensureuser even though ive used it serverside many times.  Thanks alot your a genuis