# Get SharePoint user ID from name or email using JavaScript

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, jsom

I am building a JavaScript web part that queries a SharePoint list and generates a report based on the list data. I want to be able to get the user ID for a given user by their name or email.

input - User Name: "jdoe"
output - User ID: 12

Can this be accomplished using JavaScript? If so, can anyone provide a link to where I can read about how to do so?

Thank you

Comment: Are you trying to retrieve the SharePoint User ID or the value in the User ID column of your list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can get user ID by the login name - using the below REST API query :

```
http://<site url>/_api/web/sitegroups(<group id>)/users(@v)?@v='<login name>'

http://<site url>/_api/web/siteusers(@v)?@v='<login name>'
```

Similar question is discussed here :

[How To Get User Id Using Login Name in Share Point Provider Hosted App](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/160684/how-to-get-user-id-using-login-name-in-share-point-provider-hosted-app)

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!