# Assign peoplepicker value in sharepoint from ASP.Net Web API 2.0

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-rest-api, sharepoint-on-prem, person-or-group

I have an API developed in ASP.net Web API 2.0 which inserts records into SharePoint 2013 list.

I am able to assign values to all the fields from the API except for the people picker fields, says

> Invalid look-up value.\n\nA look-up field contains invalid data. Please check the value and try again.

My request body is:

```
{ "siteurl":"http://intranet.sbl.com/GAD/", "listname":"Appointment", "jsonfields":"{\"Title\":\"Test1\",\"Description\":\"Description1\",\"Appointment_x0020_Detail\":\"Description1\",\"Assign_x0020_To\":\"sbl\\\\roman.bajracharya\"}" }
```

Where `"Assign_x0020_To":"sbl\\roman.bajracharya"` is the value I am passing for the people picker with title Assign To, and "sbl" is the AD domain and "roman.bajracharya" is the username.

Can anybody help me out on this?

Answer (score 0):

To add/update Person or Group field, you need the Id of user. Lets say, user Id in SharePoint site is 11 and the internal name of the field is `Assign_x0020_To`.

So the request will be like:

```
var data = {
    Assign_x0020_ToId: 11
};
```

If multiple user selection is enabled on Person or group field, you can set it's value like:

```
Assign_x0020_ToId: { 'results': [11,22] }
```

**Note**: You need to add `Id` with the field's internal name. You can get the internal name of your person or group column by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)

Comment: Thank you Ganesh for the reply. But what do I pass for the case when I have the users pulled in from the Active Directory?

Comment: In that case, first you need to [ensureUser](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-visio/jj245233(v=office.15)) on SharePoint site & then add it in person or group field. check this for more info: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/142984/create-new-sharepoint-user-with-rest-api